# What is the widgets I should use in the following stock portfolio app

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I came from Java Swing background. I am interested to have my own portfolio app which looks similar to the following.

[image]

I know that, I need `TabHost`.

I may need `ListView` as tab content, if I want the item highlighted in white rectangle click-able. When user clicks within white rectangle region, the transaction details will be shown.

**What I do not know is that, what is the widget I should use, so that I can get the stuff within the white rectangle region?**

- A green bar on the left.
- A mix of grid layout and border layout view, with information aligned properly, separated by line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may take a linear layout in horizontal orientation with an ImageView on the left for the bar and a [TableLayout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html#tablelayout) on the right

Comment: I do not understand the TabLayout on the right? How can the TabLayout having looking like grid with 4 rows? The first 3 rows is having 2 columns each, and the 4th row is having 1 column.

Comment: I meant TableLayout - sorry. So basically put a table on the right